# Yii2 Basic Template UrlManager rules for web/index

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii-url-manager

I've made an REST API in the Yii2 Basic Template. For this REST API i've changed the web.php. This is what I have added:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            //basic/web
            //basic/web/users
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['user', 'car']],
            //basic/web/countries
            //Id is een string, vandaar de tokens
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'country', 'tokens' => ['{id}' => '<id:\\w+>']],
        ],
    ],
```

This works fine. But now I can't acces the index page from the web folder anymore. What rule do I need to add to access the pages from the web folder again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' =>    '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['user', 'car']],
        //basic/web/countries
        //Id is een string, vandaar de tokens
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'country', 'tokens' => ['{id}' => '<id:\\w+>']],
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried something like this before, but for some reason it works now :)

Comment: It gives me a new problem. I can't just get 1 value with the API. For example: web/users gives all the users. but web/user/1 gives an 404 error page

Comment: '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>', This rule is the reason the id's don't work anymore